# Creating an XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to create a file (if it already exists, overwrite) with certain elements from a URL.

The url gives me an RSS feed which is in XML format, I want to simply copy that xml and use it to create an xml file named "feed"

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://example.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss"); 
if ($xml === false) { 
foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) { 
echo "Error: " . $error->message . "<br />"; 
} 
} 

print_r($xml); 

?>
```

Is what I've got, for now it just reads the file, I just need the commands to copy certain elements and paste them on the file and just name it. I found this section of code that helps me, but how do I get the information from elements of original xml document?

Like, is there any commands that resemble something like:

```
$title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 $artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 $album=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ALBUM")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 $track=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TRACK")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

So I can later do something like:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml_album = $xml->createElement($artist);
$xml_album = $xml->createElement($album);
$xml_track = $xml->createElement($track);
$xml_album->appendChild( $xml_track );
$xml->appendChild( $xml_album );

$xml->save("rootFolder/xmls/"+$title ".xml");
```

How can I arrange this?

*Album is child of artist, track is child of album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual [**the manual is a great place to start**](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Basically `simplexml_load_file` returns a SimpleXMLElement object so you don't have to use `getElementsByTagName` (that is for a DOMDocument object). You would access nodes like this (making up some document structure here):

```
$xml->artists[0]->albums->album[0]->title;
```

You can access each node in your XML document and modify them or add more. Then you can save it like this:

```
$xml->asXml('artists.xml');
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you very much!! If I would like to append  when saving something can it be done like this? $xml->asXml($filename . '.xml');?

Comment: Sure, the parameter can be a variable that contains the file's name. But you must know where you write it if you want to be able to use it later ;)

Comment: Two last questions! 1. I understand that $character = $movies->movie[0]->characters->addChild('character'); $character->addChild('name', 'Mr. Parser');
$character->addChild('actor', 'John Doe'); adds to the document,is there any way to print it with a format and not on a single line?

Comment: Print the XML file to output it in a browser? I'm not sure I follow you... Do you have an example?